# Difference between bundle and gem install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I am pretty sure this is a very basic question but as a RoR newbie I'd like to understand why sometimes I use bundle install (which from my undertanding install all Gems and their dependecies from Gemfile) and gem install [gemname]?

What are the fundamental differences between both and when would I favour gem install instead of bundle install?

Thanks!
Rog

Comment: thank you for asking this... ror tutorials were driving me crazy as they seem to interchange the terms.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd say: by default on your local machine, no particular difference but...

The purpose of `bundle install` is to setup everything for the application containing the `Gemfile`. You can even pass arguments to make needed gems installed in whatever folder you want.

This way in production, you have clearly separated apps with their own gems.

On the other side, `gem install gmaps4rails` (*easy advertisement*) gets the gem installed for your whole environment.

Comment: so based on what you are saying, may I also say that `rubygem` is a  Ruby dependency manager for machine, and `bundler` is a Ruby dependency manager for Ruby apps? :)

Answer (score 7):

I used to think there's no difference between adding a gem to the gemfile and then running 'bundle install' or doing 'gem install x'. I thought it's similar to doing 'yarn add package' vs. adding the package to package.json and then running 'yarn'.

However, while trying to set up the chamber gem for rails, I noticed how only after running 'gem install chamber' I was able to use the chamber command 'chamber init'. Before, when I had only added it to the gemfile and hit bundle install, running 'chamber init' would get me a 'unknown command chamber' error in my terminal.

Interesting..

Almost seems like running 'gem install' adds it to the global available gems (and hence terminal can run the package's commands), whereas adding it to the gemfile and running bundle install only adds it to the application. Similar to npm install --global.

Comment: that's basically it. For you to be able to run the same command using the project based version of your gem (the one in the `Gemfile`) you have to run `bundle exec chamber init`.